# nullptr & delete (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, null

I do not know the exact mechanism of **nullptr** and **delete** keyword.

#### *1

```
type* var=new type;
var=nullptr;
```

#### *2

```
type* var=new type;
delete var;
```

I know *1 and *2 are different but not how do they work exactly.

*1, *2 memory related... IDK jst wnna know difference. And when can use **nullptr** & **delete** keyword. Mixing these is impossible?

Comment: 1 leaks memory, while 2 doesn't.

Comment: `delete var;` destroys the actual object pointed to by `var`. `var = nullptr;` sets the pointer `var` to `nullptr` but leaves the object `var` used to point to intact. They don't do close to the same thing. I don't know what you mean by "mixing these is impossible?"

Comment: You should not use [new/delete (coding guidelines R.11)](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly) (unless you are deep down in a custom data structure). Use [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) . e.g. `auto var = std::make_unique<type>()` and then either let `var` go out of [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) (and the allocated memory will be deleted) or call `var.reset();` to release the memory manually. Rationale : avoid memory leaks like you have in *1

Comment: Consider `new` as a very advanced C++ technique.  Unless you are very advanced in C++, don't use it.

Comment: Pretty much: 1. You have a thing but forget where it is and can't find it again; 2. You have a thing and throw it away for good, but  you can remember where it used to be.

Comment: You can reasonably say that option 1 does not work. Your program is not going to crash (at least not immediately) but you have leaked memory and you have a `type` object which is inaccessible and therefore never going to get destroyed.

Comment: Side note: `type var=new type;` defines a variable of `type`, not `type *` and cannot accept the `type *` returned by `new type`.

Comment: @Eljay That is a good way of putting it. And this is why most datastructure classes got it wrong. They do NOT teach C++, they teach datastructures using something that is more like "C' + classes.

Comment: Voted to reopen. With any reasonable reading of the question, it's clear what's being asked. If you can't figure it out you're being deliberately obtuse. I can't for the life of me imagine why someone would write a comment that sketches an answer and then vote to close the question as unclear.

Comment: @JesperJuhl   The first example does not do `delete nullptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_type *ptr = new my_type;
ptr = nullptr;
```

After the first line, `ptr` points at an object of type `my_type` that was allocated on the free store. After the second line, `ptr` points at nothing valid. The `my_type` object on the free store still exists, but there is nothing in this code that can get at it, because the original pointer has been overwritten with a null pointer. This is called a "memory leak".

```
my_type *ptr = new my_type;
delete ptr;
```

Now, after the second line, the `my_type` object that was allocated on the free store has been destroyed (i.e., its destructor has been run) and the memory that it occupied has been freed up so that it can be used later in a subsequent call to `new`. The value in `ptr` is still the old pointer value, but because of the `delete` it no longer points at anything useful. This is called a "dangling pointer".

There's nothing inherently bad about a dangling pointer; if `delete ptr;` was the last line in a function, when the function returned `ptr` would no longer exist, so there would be no danger of trying to access the `my_type` object that no longer exists.

But sometimes it isn't so easy, and it **may** be appropriate to mark `ptr` as not pointing at a valid object by setting it to a null pointer:

```
my_type *ptr = new my_type;
delete ptr;
ptr = nullptr;
```

Now, if you need to check it, you can say

```
if (ptr)
  // do something with the thing that ptr points at
```